# Using Jetbrains Youtrack + TeamCity + TFS

Tags: tfs, teamcity, youtrack

Were using TFS for Source control and Team City for CI.

I'd like to introduce YouTrack also to the mix.

What's the integration between the three of them like?

Eg Can I raise bugs in YouTrack against product backlog items (a "story") in TFS?

Cheers for any pearls of wisdom!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integration environment you describe TFS would act just like a VCS, so no, you won't be able to raise bugs in YT against a story in TFS.

However, you will be able to modify state of a YT issue by simply mentioning it in a commit comment like *#ISS-123 fixed*. You'll be able to view commits related to an issue in YT.
In TC you will see which issues relate to a build.